# NSTimer is ruining all of my animations

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, autolayout, nstimer, uianimation

I have added an NSTimer which updates my interface, mainly labels with information 10 times every second. It calls a function which dispatches the work back to the main thread.

The view controller also has a scroll view. I have a paging system where I animate my scroll view's moving from page to page as a user taps on the tab (a button) which corresponds to each tab. That scrolling animation has just stopped happening - it is as if I am calling scrollToRect with animation as NO, even though I am calling it with YES.

I think that because I am updating my labels, auto layout is doing something dodgy in the background and ruining my scroll view animations. The same is happening for other animations which are using layout constraints to move views.

I know there are issues with Autolayout and NSTimer.

What can I do to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: If you create a subclass of your `UILabel` and override `intrinsicSize` to always return a constant value, it may not try to mess with constraint layout when you update the text. Not 100% sure on that, though.

Comment: You could try setting a boolean before you begin the animation and if this is set have your timer method defer updates.  At the end of the animation clear the boolean and refresh the data

Comment: That's exactly what I just tried! A 'timer lock' variable which causes the timer's block to just return rather than update the interface. Doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: The problem with the intrinsic size solution is that I actually need some of the labels to change in size when they update.

Comment: Right, instead of using [sv scrollToVisibleRect..], I used [UIView animate...]. I set the timer lock to YES before the block and in the completion handler I set the timer lock back to NO. This does fix the problem. If you want to offer your comment as an answer, ill accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a boolean flag that inhibits the updates from the timer method.  Set this to `true` just before you begin the animations and `false` once the animation completes.  You probably also want to update the data 'manually' once the animation completes to capture any blocked updates.